# Вызвано исключение по адресу (ntdll.dll) в prog.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу

Tags: c++, массивы, visual-studio, строки, файлы

Полный текст ошибки:

```
Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x0000000077A60EB7 (ntdll.dll) в prog.exe:
0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0x000009E2CF156B88
```

Возникает при выполнении следующей части кода:

```
PWSTR fr;
/* получаю %USERPROFILE%\Desktop текущего пользователя */
SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Desktop, 0, NULL, &fr);
/* записываю в константу файл который хочу создать в Desktop */
const wchar_t fileName[10] = L"\\file.exe";
unsigned int fileNameLen = 0;
while (fileName[fileNameLen] != NULL) { //узнаю длину названия файла
    fileNameLen++;
}
unsigned int frLen = 0;
while (fr[frLen] != NULL) { //узнаю длину пути к Desktop
    frLen++;
}
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < fileNameLen; i++) { //конкат fr + fileName
    fr[frLen + i] = fileName[i];
}
```

Вероятнее всего, ошибка в конкатенации. Я так и не понял чем считается символ backslash `\\`, потому что при объявлении переменной `fileName[10]` он занимает два места (размер переменной `9` вместо `10` поставить не получится, хотя реально знаков в названии 9), но при прибавлении (конкатенации) к `fr` в debug отображается как один символ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вы же сами дали команду:

```
while (fr[frLen] != NULL)  //узнаю длину пути к Desktop
    frLen++;
```

а значит `fr[frLen] == NULL` т.е. начиная с этого места вы уже будете выходить за пределы массива, а вы еще хотите читать в `fr[frLen + i]`  в последнем цикле.

Comment: `fr` будет возвращать `NULL` когда у нее закончатся используемые места, но неиспользуемые ведь остаются все равно. Так что цикл `while` считает сколько из мест заняты. А в незанятые могут быть еще символы записаны. В отладчике видно что строка изменяется до необходимого результата, а когда выполняется следующая команда после конкатенации возникает ошибка.

Comment: А кто вам сказал, что `fr` будет содержать достаточно пустого места для добавления в нее имени файла? [В описании](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath) просто сказано, что в указателе - адрес строки, которую вы потом должны освободить. Но не сказано, что количества выделенной памяти достаточно, чтоб туда еще что-то дописывать.

Comment: @Harry Сделать новую `wchar_t` переменную длиной 255 мест, записал в неё результат конкатенации `fr` и `fileName`, ошибки не возникло. Спасибо за помощь